# mail-filter-expression to match subject and sender email

Tags: regex, email, jakarta-mail, spring-integration

I am working on a project that requires loading new incoming emails, read the email that only passed the filtering criteria (Subject start with "AAA", sender email is "BBB@gmail.com"). I use spring integration, but I am not familiar with regular expression, I wrote expression like this, but not working for me. Please help.

(subject matches '(?i)AAA.*')|(sender matches '(?i).*BBB@gmail.com.*')

```
<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="customAdapter"
    store-uri="imaps://some_google_address:${password}@imap.gmail.com/INBOX"
    channel="receiveChannel"
    should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
    java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
    mail-filter-expression="(subject matches '(?i)AAA.*')|(sender matches '(?i).*BBB@gmail.com.*')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

for mail filter expression try

For matching mail subject

`payload.subject matches 'criteria'`

For matching mail sender try

```
payload.from[0].address matches 'my@example.com'
```

you can surely add both with and operator